# I have bitcoin in an armory wallet - how do I get the Bitcoin Cash

Tags: bitcoin-core, armory

I have an amount on bitcoin in an armory wallet from a year ago, and have never moved the coins.

How do I get the bitcoin cash coins from this?

Can I just install the bitcoin cash client and restore with my armory passphrase?